# MediaPlayer not always playing audio in UWP app

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-10-iot-core

I'm working on a UWP app (running on a Raspberry Pi running Windows 10 IoT), and I need to play sound at certain times each day.  I initialize a MediaPlayer and StorageFile by calling the following method:

```
private async void prepPlayer() {
            file = await StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync(new Uri("ms-appx:///audio.mp3"));
            player = new MediaPlayer();

}
```

and then I call it when I want audio played by calling the following method:

```
public async void playAudio(){
            player.SetFileSource(file);
            player.Play();    
}
```

The problem I'm having is that after a few times of playAudio getting called, it quits playing the audio.  I can't reproduce this with the debugger running.  Any ideas?

Comment: When the app quits the audio playing, is there any exception thrown?Which audio output device did you use? Does the method `playAudio` run in a timer?

Comment: The app continues running without crashes, so I don't think there is any exception being thrown (I'm not catching any).  I used the only output device I have available, which is the Pi's 3.5mm audio jack.  The playAudio method is supposed to trigger twice a day at a certain time, and gets called conditionally from a timer method (playAudio is supposed to get called twice a day, and the timer method gets called every second).

Comment: Which build did you test the issue? Have you tried to use a USB audio device instead of 3.5mm audio jack?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:
Open **Package.appxmanifest**.
Click **Capabilities** tab.
Tick **Background Media Playback**
My requirement is almost same. My app should play different audio files on 5 different times per day. Whatever I developed till now is working well.